# Retrieve the windows user which connects to a linux server

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core, server, client

I have a web application deployed on a linux server. When a user connects to this server, we want to display its username on the banner of the page.

To make things easy for sample, the razor homepage is like this :

```
<div>
 @userName
</div>

@code {
  private string userName;

  protected override void OnInitialized()
    {   
        PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
        powerShell.AddCommand("whoami");
        var result = powerShell.Invoke();

        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
           userName = result[0].BaseObject.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            userName = string.Empty;    
        }
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

}
```

And if I execute this, I wont get 'Jérémy J' as I am the person which connects to the server but I retrieve the name of the logged person on the server (here 'LinServ0Dev'), but I need to retrieve 'Jérémy J'...

What is the command in PowerShell (or other technic) to retrieve the name of the user which connect to the server ?

Comment: There's no way to know without requiring authentication. How are users currently authenticated (logging in) in your web app?

Comment: Argh... At this time, thé company I work for doesn't want to hear about authentication... (because only 5 users will use the site they said) So users dont authenticate on the server.

Comment: Well, then you can't know, simple as that. Maybe you can use this feature request to convince the application owner otherwise ;-)

Comment: That's the point... I will try tomorrow

Comment: `a user connects to this server` how to connect? is it possible to send the user name to your application when user connects to the server? Hmmm it sounds like some of the authentication.. Any way I agree with Mathias R. Jessen